# Why SNR Down Decrease during the time?

Tags: noise, adsl

I have an ADSL service. here is my ADSL Log: 
SNR Up : 18.5 
SNR Down : 7.9 
Line Attenuation Up: 24.6 
Line Attenuation Down: 40.4 
Data Rate Up: 1022 
Data Rate Down: 9845 
As you may see my Attenuation Down is very high. 
But my real problem is SNR Down. 
When I turn off the modem and turn it on again my SNR Down will be 10. 
But it decreases during the time. it's 7.9 right now. and if I don't restart modem it will be 4 or 5 after some hours and this decreasement will affect on my data rate down and will decrease it to 4000. 
Please tell me why this happens? why my SNR Down will decrease during the time? 
Thanks
(I've asked this question in Serverfault and someone commented that I have to send this question here.)

Comment: Speak to your ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNR means *sound to noise ratio*. It is an average over time. When you first turn he modem on, the ratio is an arbitrary short-time average Over time, as more noise bursts on the line are integrated, it changes. To affect that, i.e. to increase the ratio (improve the signal) requires improvement in the physical line connecting the modem to the ISP. See [SpeedGuide.net](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-cable-modem-signal-levels-are-considered-good-78), [Increase Broadband Speed](https://www.increasebroadbandspeed.co.uk/SNR-tweak), your ISP, and the modem manufacturers guide.